# Cowplot plot_grid remove space from ggplot facet strips

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am assembling two ggplot objects with `plot_grid`, each of which uses the same facets, to give an effect of a grid of plots but with different x-axes. I only need the facet text to be on the first ggplot object, however, `plot_grid` seems to preserve space for the removed facet strips in the second plot.
Is there a way around this, or a different way to achieve this effect with cowplot?

As an example, here is some code I have:

```r
dat <- tibble(x1=1:10, x2=20:11, y=rnorm(x2/2 - x1), lab=rep(c("A", "B"), 5))

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x1, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~lab, nrow=1) +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "in"))

p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x2, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~lab, nrow=1) +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "in")

plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow=2, align="h")
```

[image]

I can remove the facets from the bottom row just fine:

```r
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x2, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~lab, nrow=1) +
    theme(
        plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "in"), 
        strip.background=element_blank(), 
        strip.text=element_blank()
    )

p2
```

[image]

But when I add to the grid, the space for the strips suddenly appears again:

```r
plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow=2, align="h")
```

[image]

Interestingly, when I remove the strips from both rows, the spacing for both rows is correctly absent.

What's going on here? Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after ?

[image]

You can achieve this by removing all elements for the first plot:
(either in your `p1` call or `plot_grid`)

```
library(ggpubr)

plot_grid(p1 +
            rremove("xlab") +
            theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x=element_blank()),
          p2,
          nrow = 2)
```

Comment: I would still like the x-axis title to be there for the top row. Interestingly, this also removes the strip space though. My issue seems like it may be an internal problem with `plot_grid`